# Which one has better performance: add and remove event listener on every render VS running an useEffect to update a ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here's my situation:

I've got a custom hook, called `useClick`, which gets an HTML `element` and a `callback` as input, attaches a `click` **event listener** to that `element`, and sets the `callback` as the **event handler**.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    if (myState === 3) {
      console.log("I will only count until 3...");
      return;
    }
    setMyState(prevState => prevState + 1);
  }

  useClick(buttonRef, handleClick);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update counter</button>
      {"Counter value is: " + myState}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useClick.js**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function useClick(element, callback) {
  console.log("Inside useClick...");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Inside useClick useEffect...");
    const button = element.current;

    if (button !== null) {
      console.log("Attaching event handler...");
      button.addEventListener("click", callback);
    }
    return () => {
      if (button !== null) {
        console.log("Removing event handler...");
        button.removeEventListener("click", callback);
      }
    };
  }, [element, callback]);
}

export default useClick;
```

Note that with the code above, **I'll be adding and removing the event listener on every call of this hook** (because the callback, `which is handleClick` changes on every render). And it must change, because it depends on the `myState` variable, that changes on every render.

And I would very much like to **only add the event listener on mount and remove on dismount.** Instead of adding and removing on every call.

---

Here on SO, someone have suggested that I coulde use the following:

**useClick.js**

```
function useClick(element, callback) {
    console.log('Inside useClick...');

    const callbackRef = useRef(callback);

    useEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    const callbackWrapper = useCallback(props => callbackRef.current(props), []);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Inside useClick useEffect...');
        const button = element.current;

        if (button !== null) {
            console.log('Attaching event handler...');
            button.addEventListener('click', callbackWrapper);
        }
        return () => {
            if (button !== null) {
                console.log('Removing event handler...');
                button.removeEventListener('click', callbackWrapper);
            }
        };
    }, [element, callbackWrapper]);
}
```

**QUESTION**

It works as intended. It only adds the event listener on mount, and removes it on dismount.

The code above uses a **callback wrapper that uses a ref that will remain the same across renders** (so I can use it as the event handler and mount it only once), and its `.current` property it's updated with the new callback on every render by a `useEffect` hook.

**The question is:** performance-wise, which approach is the best? Is running a `useEffect()` hook less expensive than adding and removing event listeners on every render?

Is there anyway I could test this?

Comment: Why not just use <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>My button</button>? You don't have to create a hook for events that already exists on the DOM elements. you can even do <div onClick={...}>...</div> for non input elements.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @ItayGanor hey Itay, I confess that I don't remember what I was going to use that for. But today, 1.5 years later, I think that if you are not going to do something ultra specific which will demand all sorts of performance optimizations, the difference is negligible. That being said, I haven't tested to know for sure which one would have the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  // handleClick remains unchanged
  const handleClick = useCallback(
    () => setMyState(prevState => prevState >= 3 ? 3 : prevState + 1),
    []
  );

  useClick(buttonRef, handleClick);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update counter</button>
      {"Counter value is: " + myState}
    </div>
  );
}
```

A more professional answer:

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const [myState, handleClick] = useReducer(
    prevState => prevState >= 3 ? 3 : prevState + 1,
    0
  );

  useClick(buttonRef, handleClick);

  return (
    <div>
      <button ref={buttonRef}>Update counter</button>
      {"Counter value is: " + myState}
    </div>
  );
}
```